# Prove $ \limsup a_n$ is a real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

($a_n$) is a real sequence bounded **only from above**. Let $S :=$ {$t \in \Bbb R:$ $t$ is the limit of a convergent subsequence of ($a_n$) }. Suppose the supremum of S is a real number.

Prove that $ \limsup _{n \to \infty} ~ a_n$ is also a real number.

I was given the definition of the limit superior as: $$\limsup a_n = \inf_{\forall m} \sup_{n \ge m} a_n$$

I think this is a part of the proof showing $$\limsup a_n = \sup S = \inf_{\forall m} \sup_{n \ge m} a_n$$,but I'm not sure where to start. I know the property that if the sequence is bounded (both from above and below), then  $ \limsup a_n$ is real. But in this case, the sequence is only bounded from above, given the assumption that $Sup S$ is also a real number. I'm also stuck when trying to prove by contradiction. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $\sup S \in \mathbb R$, then that means there is at least one subsequence that converges. Let $L\in\mathbb R$ be the limit of that subsequence. Then $L\leq \lim \sup a_n$.

Comment: Actually $L=\limsup_n a_n$.

Comment: @REr Yes, that's true. I just thought it might be easier to show that the $\lim\sup$ is bounded below.

Comment: Could you explain why $L\le limsup a_n $?

Comment: Sure. Let $(a_{k_i})$ be the subsequence that approaches $L$. Fix $m\in\mathbb N$. We can show that $\underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n \geq L$ as follows: If $\underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n = L - \epsilon$ (i.e. the supremum is lower than $L$), then pick the $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_{k_n} - L| < \epsilon$ for $n\geq N$. So let $r=\max\{m, N\}$. Thus $|a_{k_r} - L| < \epsilon$ and $L-\epsilon < a_{k_r}$, which contradicts our assumption that $\underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n = L - \epsilon$.

Comment: So if $\underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n \geq L$ for $m\in\mathbb N$, then $\inf_{m\in\mathbb N}\underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n \geq L$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the steps. But I also got a hint that there's another way to prove the problem by contradiction, and I'm stuck on it. My thought is to assume $\lim sup_{x \to \infty} a_n $ is not a real number, i.e. it goes to $ \infty$ or $ -\infty$, then the assumption won't hold. Is this right? Do you know how to continue with this idea?

Comment: Well assuming that $\lim\sup a_n$ is not real, it would have to be $-\infty$ since the series is bounded from above. One way to do the proof is to show that no subsequence converges on $\mathbb R$. So let $b_m = \underset{n\geq m}{\sup} a_n$ for $m\in\mathbb N$. Note that each $b_m$ is real since $a_n$ is bounded above, so  the supremum cannot be $+\infty$. You can then argue that $b_m \to -\infty $ as $m\to \infty$. If $(a_{k_i})$ is a subsequence, then it is bounded above by $(b_{k_i})$ and thus must also diverge to $-\infty$.  Therefore $S=\emptyset$, which contradicts $\sup S \in\mathbb R$